# Open Mass action Url in New Tab in the Admin grids

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, grid

Is this Possible to Open Mass Action target url with submitted data in New tab or Window in Magento. I have tried and searched for this but not find any solution.

```
$this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('id', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Label'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('url'),
        ));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the file `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/massaction.phtml` there is a `<form>` tag on line 46.
If you add `target="_blank"` to this element the actions will be executed in a new tab / window.

Best option would be to create an extension that overwrites this file.
You can do this by extending / rewriting the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction_Abstract` class and edit the `__construct` function where the template file is set on line 51.

Comment: Can you help me to overwrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction_Abstract` this class. One More doubt I have is, if we overwrite and added `target="_blank"` in new template file .. is this apply on every massaction dropdown. I need to apply this on Sales order grid only.

Comment: Hi Pankaj, please take a look at this article: http://magentocustom.blogspot.nl/2011/05/how-to-override-magento-block-classes.html. In your case it would mean you overwrite the block `adminhtml/widget_grid_massaction_abstract`.

You could use an `if else` statement to make the switch of templates only in the sales grid.

See this article http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/08/22/magento-get-route-name-module-name-controller-and-action-name-from-url/ to get the controller name and only switch templates on the `sales` controller.

Comment: thanks Sander .. I was missing adminhtml in class. its working fine now. I will try to add form target attribute on particular option from mass action action. thanks once again.